# Commit objects to Database

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm having some trouble committing records to the database. When I click a button, I download records from the website, the objects are there in memory and everything works fine but these objects are only committed to core data when I actually close the app. Is there anyway to commit them to core data straight away, without having to close the app.

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the following method on your [NSManagedObjectContext](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:):

> Attempts to commit unsaved changes to
>   registered objects to their persistent
>   store.

```
- (BOOL)save:(NSError **)error
```