# UPDATE query only works in simulator

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite

I am using the firefox sqlite manager to help me building an iphone app. In which I include an UPDATE query, which works perfectly in the iPhone simulator. However, it fails when I run from the real machine (the iphone). There is no error, it just does not update the db.

I am thinking of two possible causes:
1) The db it updates is not the one as in simulator
2) The db I read is not the one that is updated

Does anyone have similar experience?

Code as follows:

```
        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Exercises.sqlite"];

        BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
        }
        if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"An error has occured.");
        }

        NSString *ranID = [@"UPDATE Status SET money = " stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d", money + 100];

        const char *sql2 = [ranID UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement2;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql2, -1, &sqlStatement2, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement 2");
        }
        if (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement2)==SQLITE_ROW) 
            NSLog(@"succeed");
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happening is that you are trying to write inside the database that is in your bundle, you dont have write access to files in your bundle, you will need to copy it to Documents directory if you want to update the database

To copy the database file

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Exercises.sqlite"];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:dbPath toPath:documentsPath error:NULL];
```

Then always use the new file path (`documentsPath`)to access the database

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. What do meant by Documents dir and how do you copy a database?

Answer (score 0):

Files in your app's bundle are read-only on device.

You should copy it to somewhere in your app's sandbox first, such as in your Library/Application Support directory. (You can use - [NSFileManager URLsForDirectory:inDomains:] with NSApplicationSupportDirectory to find this path; be sure to create the directory before you try to write to it.)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are not committing our changes. See similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053362/how-to-commit-changes-in-sqlite) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523741/commit-objects-to-database)